# The std::less<int>()(int, int) might get a wrong answer

Tags: c++, stl

I am learning the SplayTree. When I write my code, I get a mistake as what the title says. This mistake appears at my "splay" mathod:

```
void splay(const KeyType& arg_key, Node*& tree)
```

this line:

```
if (key_less(arg_key, key(tree)))
```

I tried to output some message about this line and found it always get a 'true' answer

code:

```
std::cerr << "arg_key == " << arg_key << "; key(tree) == " << key(tree) << std::endl;
std::cerr << "key_less(arg_key, key(tree)) == " << key_less(arg_key, key(tree)) << std::endl;
std::cerr << "key_less(key(tree), arg_key) == " << key_less(key(tree), arg_key) << std::endl;
std::cerr << "typename of key_less == " << typeid(key_less).name() << std::endl;
```

output:

```
arg_key == 2; key(tree) == 8
key_less(arg_key, key(tree)) == 0
key_less(key(tree), arg_key) == 1
typename of key_less == struct std::less<int>
```

The splay tree template is like that

```
template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType, typename KeyOfValue, typename Comparator = std::less<KeyType>> class SplayTree
```

I define a splay tree as that

```
struct GetKeyFromValue
{
    int operator()(int value)
    {
        return value;
    }
};
SplayTree<int, int, GetKeyFromValue, std::less<int>> tree;
```

when I change the last template argument to

```
    struct Comparator
    {
        bool operator()(int lhs, int rhs)
        {
            return lhs < rhs;
        }
    };
    SplayTree<int, int, GetKeyFromValue, Comparator> tree;
```

It can get the right answer:

```
arg_key == 2; key(tree) == 8
key_less(arg_key, key(tree)) == 1
key_less(key(tree), arg_key) == 0
typename of key_less == struct `int __cdecl main(void)'::`2'::Comparator
```

Is it a bug?

thanks very much for watching my problem.

I am really looking forward to your help.

P.S.
My platform is Visual Studio 2019 16.7.1 on Windows10 1909.

Comment: On the face of it, it looks like a bug, but there's too much missing code to be sure. You need to put together a [mre].

Comment: It's hard to envisage a situation in which `std::less` would compare two `int`s incorrectly.  It is easy to implement, easy to verify, and enough programmers would use it that a bug would have been detected a long time ago.   The problem is almost certainly in some code you haven't shown.   Assuming that `arg_key` is `int`, one candidate is that `key(tree)` returns a type that has some behaviour (e.g. working of an `operator int()`) that isn't what you assume.

Comment: As @Peter mentioned, it's hard to believe that `std::less<int>` would have an error in it. Visual Studio comes with a debugger shipped with it, you should set up some conditional breakpoints where the comparison is taking place, and see it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Peter!! As what you mentioned, the problem happens in `key(tree)`. the definition of it is

```
static const KeyType& key(Node* node_ptr) { return KeyOfValue()(node_ptr->value); }
```

in this case, the `KeyOfValue` is a class which i write it carelessly:

```
struct GetKeyFromValue
    {
        int operator()(int value)
        {
            return value;
        }
    };
```

after i change it to

```
struct GetKeyFromValue
    {
        const int& operator()(const int& value)
        {
            return value;
        }
    };
```

everything is ok now.
I think this problem might be the `key(tree)` returned a `const int&` reference to a temporary value that `GetKeyFromValue::operator()(int)` returned?

Thank you to everyone who can read my question and don't hesitate to enlighten me.